# In VSC, how can I enable "Go to File" to search *all* of the files within a project, including dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In recent months I switched from using NetBeans to Visual Studio Code, and I like it a lot, but I haven't been able to figure out how to quickly open a given dependency file, searching by name.

[image]

Even though the file definitely exists, I get no results:

[image]

(This feature only seems to work to find the *main* files of my project rather than any dependency files.)

Manually expanding the "node_modules" folder and looking for the particular file is really time-consuming and annoying.

How can I search for a file directly, like NetBeans allows?

Comment: Do these links help : [link1](https://dinohensen.nl/vscode-enable-searching-node-modules) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search-in-vs-code)?

Comment: @harrymc Perfect! Thank you so much! The combination of those 2 hints was what really worked. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search-in-vs-code#comment114098298_33418660 If you post an answer here, I'll accept it. Or if you want to close as a duplicate, that would be fine too.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but to write an answer I'll to know which method you used from link2. In any case, your question isn't a duplicate - stackoverflow.com is a different site.

Comment: @harrymc I removed `node_modules` from `"search.exclude"` in VSC ➔ File ➔ Preferences ➔ Settings ➔ User/Workspace Settings. And I unchecked "Use Ignore Files".

Comment: Answer posted - feel free to comment upon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the two links below, the poster has enabled "Go to File" to search all
the files within the project, including dependencies, by doing the following
in *File > Preferences > Settings > User/Workspace Settings*:

- Remove `node_modules` from "search.exclude"
- Uncheck "Use Ignore Files".

References:

- [enable searching through node_modules using vscode](https://dinohensen.nl/vscode-enable-searching-node-modules/)
- [Choose folders to be ignored during search in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search-in-vs-code)